# how to grab the Ctl from a linkbutton

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview which is pulling it data from a stored procedure. In the column title, I have used a Linkbutton. I would like to grab the Ctl ID and store it in a variable when it is clicked. I am not sure what is happening, but I get a few strings going through. Below is my code and this is similar to my previous post.

ASP.NET

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkID" runat="server" OnClick="lblClick1"
            Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'>
            </asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

C#:

```
 GridViewRow row = gv2.SelectedRow;
    string controlId = ((LinkButton)row.FindControl("lnkID")).ID;
    lblshow.Text = controlId;
```

Can someone help me get up and running. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a hidden field to store the id:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField 
        runat="server" 
        ID="ID" 
        Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' 
    />

    <asp:LinkButton 
        runat="server" 
        OnClick="LabelClick" 
        Text="click me" 
    />
</ItemTemplate>
```

and then:

```
protected void LabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var hiddenField = (HiddenField)((Control)sender).FindControl("ID");
    var id = hiddenField.Value;
    // Do something with the id        
}
```

---

UPDATE:

Full working example:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            grid.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new
            {
                ID = x
            });
            grid.DataBind();
        }
    }

    protected void LabelClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var hiddenField = (HiddenField)((Control)sender).FindControl("ID");
        result.Text = string.Format("selected id: {0}", hiddenField.Value);
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView ID="grid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField 
                        runat="server" 
                        ID="ID" 
                        Value='<%#Eval("ID") %>' 
                    />
                    <asp:LinkButton 
                        runat="server" 
                        OnClick="LabelClick" 
                        Text="click me" 
                    />
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <asp:Label ID="result" runat="server" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I get this error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object when running it.

Comment: Line 29:         // Get the currently selected row using the SelectedRow property.
Line 30:         GridViewRow row = gv2.SelectedRow;
Line 31:         string controlId = ((LinkButton)row.FindControl("ID")).ID;
Line 32:         lblshow.Text = controlId;

Comment: @jpavlov, see my update with a full working example and see how it differs from your code. Adapt as necessary. Also in what you have shown you are using some `gv2.SelectedRow` and I am not sure that this will give you the desired result.

Comment: I get an error that it doesnt recoginze the >, new and { I have no idea what to look at to fix it

Answer (score 0):

In the OnClick method lblClick1 you can use:

```
public void lblClick1(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int controlId = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument); //get ID and store it in controlId
    lblshow.Text = controlId;
}
```